# JPanel being fixed size no matter what size it is set to

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to create John Conway's Game Of Life. I have a function which receives a boolean matrix, and create white square on my JPanel (the square being JPanel itself) if a cell in the matrix is set to true, and black square if false. Here is the function:

```java
 public static void applyMatrixToGamePanel(JPanel panel, boolean[][] matrix, int cubeSize)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <  matrix.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
            {

                JPanel cube = new JPanel();
                cube.setSize(cubeSize, cubeSize);
                cube.setVisible(true);
                if(matrix[i][j])
                {
                    cube.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                else
                {
                    cube.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                panel.add(cube);
            }
        }
    }
```

I pass to `panel` my main game's JPanel which I set as the only component of my main JFrame.
the problem being, that no matter what size I pass in, the squares remain at a relatively small, fixed size.
This is how it looks (painted red just to outline):
[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Why did you delete the collection of code snippets (and not add a single MRE / SSCCE)? Did you read both documents?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have read those before asking my first question. Which part do you think is lacking? Minimal or teproducible? I infred the problem is about the qustion not being minimal as it seems very long. I belive all the code was relevantm but there are some poeples with more reputation and experience than me and if they ask me to remove it just like you did I do.

Comment: *"Which part do you think is lacking?"* Well, as the author of the SSCCE document & the author of the first draft of the MRE document, I can do better than 'think'. *"Minimal or teproducible?"* Reproducible. We should be able to copy/paste the MRE / SSCCE into an IDE, and without a single change or addition, compile it, run it and see the problem. Note that an M/S might be over 100 lines of code. People tend to take the minimal / short with too much importance. Just make sure the code in them is *actually* necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Maybe this version of [Conway's Game of Life](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/conways-life) will provide some inspiration.

Comment: Don't use the setSize() method. Swing uses layout managers. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of a component based on the "preferred size" of the component. By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout and by default a FlowLayout will use 5 pixels of space before and after each component added to the panel. Since you are not adding any components, the default preferred size will be calculated as (10, 10). Change the preferred size of each panel.

Comment: However, using a JPanel is not the best solution since you will have hundreds of components each of which takes up additional memory. A better solution is to do custom painting. Based on the values in your 2D array you can simply paint a white/black rectangle whatever size you desire.